# Field Mapping doesn't create all fields in CSV export

Tags: soql, data-loader, commandline

This is my SOQL query:

```
SELECT Count(Id), Category__c FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_MONTH GROUP BY ROLLUP (Category__c) ORDER BY Category__c DESC
```

It works fine when using the DataLoader GUI, but I need to run the query using the DataLoader from the command line.  So, I created the mapping file:

```
#Mapping values
COUNT(ID)__C=COUNT
CATEGORY__C=CATEGORY
```

process.bat runs fine and executes the query, but my output csv file only contains the Category column.  I realize COUNT(ID) isn't defined until the query runs so maybe that has something to do with it?